# How do we get Rigidbody behaviour in Unity3D's Entity Component System?

Tags: unity-game-engine, entity-component-system

I'm playing with ECS. I'd like to know if it is possible to have lots of cubes with rigid bodies instantiated as entities in order to get lots more of them?

I want tens of thousands (if not more) of simple (Mesh + Collider + Rigidbody) objects in a scene just to passively interact with the scene.

Comment: Unity's base implementation of game objects *is* ECS, so, `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`. If that isn't what you're looking for, you need to better define your problem.

Comment: I want to create a Prefab that is a cube + collider + rigid body, and then create lots of ECS instances of it and have them act the same as if I had created them as game objects. @Draco18s

Comment: That's what `Instantiate` does: turns a prefab into a spawned game object just as if you'd done it yourself. Again, what's the problem?

Comment: Games run slow with lots of game object instances. ECS instances run much faster.

Comment: Well yes. That's because the new ECS system you're referring to is [a *pure data* system](https://improbable.io/blog/unity-ecs-1). As such the two cannot be directly compared and there is no easily digestible transition from using one to using the other and under pureECS things like `Rigidbody` and `GameObject` don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

[ECS is an architecture pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) which stands for entity-component-system. In answer to your question; Yes. It is possible to have many instances of simple mesh-rigidbody-collider entities, if you engineer your code in such a way to accommodate this technical requirement.  The rest of this answer is moving forward with the assumption you are referring to designing your own game engine (as the question lacks detail)

From my experience (I have designed 2 physics engines and 3 custom game engines) the major bottlenecks are as follows:

1. Graphics implementation - It doesn’t matter if you’re using OpenGL or DirectX, inexperienced or outdated graphics implementations are a huge source of custom engine bottlenecks. To remedy this, I suggest using the [modern OpenGL tutorials](https://learnopengl.com), specifically on things like deferred rendering. In DirectX, the implementations can get quite complicated as there are less learning resources available for free online (Partly due to the fact that implementation details differ largely from version to version in directx). The big new thing I’ve heard from the latest directx version is something called [mesh shaders](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/introduction-turing-mesh-shaders/) which appear to “simplify” the process.. Research will be your friend for this step
2. Physics - This can reduce frame rate especially with lots of collisions. Unless you want to be a physics programmer, I suggest using available open source implementations such as [Bullet physics](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3), an excellent C++ physics engine. PhysX is an alternative however the implementation can be daunting, and both libraries suffer from subpar or terse documentation. These libraries can be easily integrated (from a design standpoint) into a standard ECS framework.  If you are insistent on designing your own, I suggest reading through GDC presentations from people like [Erin Catto, Erwin Coumins, Gino Van den Bergen](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1015499/Physics-for-Game), Dirk Gregorius etc.

As for “tens of thousands” I can almost guarantee if they aren’t spheres, tens of thousands of passive colliders will absolutely slow down your engine with a custom physics implementation. You can trivially multithread a custom physics engine with an iterative solver in two areas; Internal Collider geometry updating (both their bounding volume and world geometry) as well as the narrowphase of collision detection. If your broadphase collision detection outputs unique pairs of potential collisions, you can easily parallelize the actual collision testing if your geometry is updated prior to this stage, as collision detection could be considered a read-only task.
The last simple optimization for physics would be to [use collision islands (see bottom of page under optimizations)](https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-iii-constrained-rigid-body-simulation), which essentially separates collisions into groups which are independent, i.e. Two janga towers would be represented by two collision islands, and each can be solved in a separate thread due to data dependencies and the nature of iterative solvers.

For tens of thousands, you may even consider experimenting with [compute shaders](https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2014-siggraph-bof/KITE-BOF_Aug14.pdf), as they are great for passive simulation of large quantities of objects. The link provided actually incorporates simple collisions in learning how to use these shaders.

Comment: Hi Jon. I'm not writing my own game engine, I'm using Unity3D.

Comment: Hi Jon. The question is tagged #Unity3D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask “... Include key APIs ...” which you didn’t do. The title clearly mentions the architecture pattern and you don’t mention your api at all in your question.

Comment: Hi Jon
I'm not sure if your interpretation is correct or not, I'd have to check. Please don't think your time was wasted though, although I cannot use it to solve my problem I found it very educational and I am very grateful for having read it, and for the time you spent on it! PS: I've added Unity3D to the question title. 
Thanks again!